# Difference between isin, str.contains and if condition?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am generally confused as to if I want to filter a dataframe column items with something, 
should `isin` or `.str.contains` or `if "aa" in df["column"]` is used?

Kindly tell me which of them are used in different cases ?

Comment: first one is ISIN and second one is IN . I have doubt in both of them

Answer (score 3):

## isin

Use `isin` if you want to check the occurrence of one of multiple strings in the **values** of a Series:

```
import pandas as pd                                                                                                      
things = pd.Series(['apple', 'banana', 'house', 'car'])                                                                                                                              
fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'kiwi']                                                                                                                                            
things.isin(fruits)
```

**Output:**

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

## .str.contains

`.str.contains` does the same but only for one string and it also matches parts of strings.

```
things.str.contains('apple')
```

**Output:**

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

```
things.str.contains('app')
```

**Output:**

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

## in

`A in series` checks whether `A` is in the **index** of the pd.Series:

```
"apple" in things                                                                                                                                                              
# Output: False
```

Our `things` series has no 'apple' in its indices, it is quickly clear why:

```
> things
0     apple
1    banana
2     house
3       car
dtype: object
```

The first column describes the index, so we can check it:

```
0 in things                                                                                                                                                              
# Output: True
```

Comment: This doesn't cover how `str.contains('some')` wil return `True` for `'something'` while others won't.

Answer (score 2):

I will try to show you the differences with examples :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [4,8], 'B': ['hello toto','foo bar']})
df_1 = df[df['B'].str.contains("hello")]
df_2 = df.isin([4, "foo bar", "hello", "hello toto mamamia"])
df_3 = df.loc[df["B"] == "foo bar"] # implicit "if"

# df
   A            B
0  4   hello toto
1  8      foo bar

# df_1
   A           B
0  4  hello toto

# df_2
       A      B
0   True  False
1  False   True

# df_3
   A        B
1  8  foo bar
```

Answer (score 1):

**isin**: `if element x in list, return True else return False`

**str.contains**: `if element x in string for string in list, return True else return False`

**if**: `if row['string'] == element x for row in df, return True else return False`

This last one is equivalent to `isin` with only 1 element in `list`.

Basically `if` & `isin` are about checking if a certain column's value is part of a list, while `str.contains` is about searching the strings in the column to find a certain substring.

Example usage:

```
df
>>
  clientID   priceType
0  ER12312      member
1  ER24421    standard
2  WB44213      member
3  ER92932  discount15
4  WB02321    standard
```

We want all clients paying member or standard price:

```
df[df.priceType.isin(['member','standard'])]
>>
  clientID priceType
0  ER12312    member
1  ER24421  standard
2  WB44213    member
4  WB02321  standard
```

And if we want all 'ER'- client IDs:

```
df[df.clientID.str.contains('ER')]
>>
  clientID   priceType
0  ER12312      member
1  ER24421    standard
3  ER92932  discount15
```